# Есть ли разница в тяжести между SQL запросами к одной таблице?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть 2 запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id;
```

и

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = :id;
```

Велика ли разница в их тяжести, если в таблице 20+ столбцов? Есть ли смысл оптимизировать путем выбора из таблицы только необходимых данных или это экономия на спичках?

И вообще, экономия ли? Может, запросы, где мы выбираем только конкретные данные тяжелей, чем выбрать всю строку?

Comment: Вообще говоря Select * это плохая практика и практически никогда не нужно использовать все столбцы. Зачем же выбирать всё?.

Comment: @gregor, дело в том, что синтаксис любого фрэймворка гораздо проще для выбора всей строки, чем для выбора конкретных данных. Поэтому ленивые программисты пишут ```select *``` даже если им нужно всего одно значение из таблицы. Сейчас стал вопрос оптимизации, есть ли смысл отлавливать такие места, чтоб база работала быстрее, или это экономия "на спичках"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если выбирать именно id, т.е. поле, которое есть в индексе по которому и работает запрос, то большинство СУБД выполнят эту операцию исключительно по индексу, не обращаясь к блоку данных таблицы, что сокращает дисковый ввод-вывод. Так же, если в таблице содержатся поля типа blob или text и т.п. их значения могут лежать на диске отдельно от основной записи и СУБД придется за ними лазить ради `*`.

Передача СУБД-клиент идет не в том же формате, как запись лежит на диске, перед передачей СУБД в любом случае конвертирует запись из формата хранения в формат передачи и обработка большего количества полей явно медленнее.

Кроме того передача большего объема данных СУБД-клиент нагружает канал передачи (даже если это просто оперативная память, обычно копирование идет через пространство ядра, что медленно).

И весь этот переданный объем клиентская библиотека работы с БД должна будет разместить у себя в оперативной памяти... А сейчас многие программисты любят помимо `select *` еще и прочитать сразу все строки в массив, что ведет к серьезному расходу оперативной памяти.

И плюс ко всему выборка `*`, если последующая работа с таблицей идет по номерам колонок в выборке, просто опасна, любое изменение структуры таблицы приведет к неработоспособности кода

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Возможно, будет более развернутый ответ, хотя общий смысл уже понял - смысл оптимизировать путем избавления от ```SELECT * ``` есть, и очень даже существенный.